# how to call a funtion whenever slide is moved in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

what i am trying to do is the i want to call a funtion whenever a slides right.but i don't know if it can be done in ionic.My ion-item-sliding code is

```
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item-sliding #item>
            <ion-item>
              <span class="heart-icon"></span>
              <h4>Slide right to Unfavorite</h4>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options side="left">
              <button ion-button (click)="favorite(item)">Favorite</button>
            </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
        </ion-list>
```

i had to tap on the favourite button to call the function but i want it whenever someone slides to right

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for slide change:
in HTML:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
```

in TS:

```
slideChanged() {
    let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    console.log('Current index is', currentIndex);
  }
```

Comment: use this: `ionDrag` 
see this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding#events

Comment: It worked but its is firing event too many times is there any way to limit it?

Comment: Okay; use this : `ionSwipe` it will fire only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-slides ionSlideWillChange="whenChangeSlide()"></ion-slides>

whenChangeSlide(){
  console.log('Do something')
}
```

Did you see the docs for [slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides), maybe can help you?